# Python regex empty line csv

Tags: python, csv

I need to process a file which is a csv with pipe separated values. The issue is that few rows have their preceeding value after few empty rows like this,

```
"xx"|"yyyyy"|"zzz"|"aaaaaaaa"|"bbbbbbb"|"cccccccc"|"dddd"|"eeeeeee"|"fffffffffff


ffff"|""|""|"iiiii"
```

I don't understand how to process it as a single row. For now I am reading the csv file as:

```
with open(r".\sample.csv","r") as f:
        for line in f:
            yield line
```

Any idea on how to resolve it? I need that row which over multiple rows to be processed as a single row and not all rows are formatted like this.

PS: I process this CSV using multiprocessing.

Answer (score 0):

The `csv` module knows how to cope with this. Don't reinvent it needlessly.

```
with open("./sample.csv","r") as f:
    for line in csv.reader(f, delimiter="|"):
        yield line
```

`csv.reader` returns a parsed sequence of fields, not the bare line.

Comment: But the point is, The CSV is huge around 10GB and I want to process each row and send it to a third party service. So, I am trying to do this in a multiprocessing fashion. By reading only 8 rows at a time and sending them and then again read it. 

And also I tried with pandas , It didn't work since it wasn't formatted well. Will this case also be covered by csv module?

Comment: I can only comment on the example you actually posted. If the CSV is actually broken, all bets are off; though the `csv` module does have the flexibility to allow you to change its strictness etc. But if the input is ambiguous, of course, you just have to guess (or give up, and/or flame whoever gave you the hosed data).

Comment: The `for` loop with a `yield` will only read one line at a time so the number of lines in the input is not really relevant at all.

Comment: Yeah the necessity to use yield keyword inside loop is just for multiprocessing